# Why CSS style is not getting applied?

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I am trying to apply this css class to asp.net GRIDVIEW PAGER but not getting applied except Margin properties.

```
.gvwCasesPager a {
     margin-left:5px;
     margin-right:5px;
     text-align:center;
     font-size:small;
     font-style:normal;
     height: 40px;
 }
```

pager in gv:

```
<PagerStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" 
            CssClass="gvwCasesPager" 
            Font-Size="Small" 
            Font-Bold="true" 
            Height="40px" />
```

Browser Output:

```
<tr class="gvwCasesPager" align="center" style="font-size:Small;font-weight:bold;height:40px;">
     <td colspan="10">
          <table>
               <tbody>
                    <tr>
                         <td><span>1</span></td>
                         <td><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$grdviewPersonalInformation','Page$2')">2</a></td>
                    </tr>
               </tbody>
          </table>
     </td>
 </tr>
```

Comment: Can you also post the outputted HTML? It's unclear what `<pagerStyle>` outputs as actual HTML.

Comment: <tr class="gvwCasesPager" align="center" style="font-size:Small;font-weight:bold;height:40px;">
      <td colspan="10"><table>
       <tbody><tr>
        <td><span>1</span></td><td><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$grdviewPersonalInformation','Page$2')">2</a></td>
       </tr>
      </tbody></table></td>
     </tr>

Comment: Can you post a screen shot of how the pager looks? I like that style.

Comment: Remove font-size  and font-weight from your grid view markup for pager.

Comment: Try adding `display: inline-block` to that `.gvwCasesPager a` selector, see if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use following markup for pager. Your original markup had the same CSS attributes that you were trying to set in the Css class for pager, and that was causing the Css class to be overridden.

```
<PagerStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" CssClass="gvwCasesPager"/>
```

Comment: but why text-align is not getting applied ?

Comment: Let me check this on my side.

Comment: It is applying. Why do you say it's not applying?